# Randomized Javascript Picture Slider

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, database, slider

I have already created a java script slider for the index of a website I am working on. It displays three images in the slider. I have a database of images resized to what I want. I want to be able to make the three images on the page to be randomly selected from a database or a array of images every time the page is reloaded/visited

How can I randomize the images of slide1, slide2 and slide3?

```
<script>
      var aca = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
      var ath = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
      var act = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
</script>

<div id="main_slide">
    <div id="slide-buttons">
      <button class='prev' onclick='mySwipe.prev()'>&lt;</button>
      <a class='links' href="http://www.hrhsfalcons.com/academics">Academics</a>
      <a class='links' href="http://www.hrhsfalcons.com/athletics">Athletics</a>
      <a class='links' href="http://www.hrhsfalcons.com/clubs">Activities</a>
      <button class='next' onclick='mySwipe.next()'>&gt;</button>
    </div>

      <script>
      document.write("<div id='mySwipe' class='swipe'><div class='swipe-wrap'>");
      document.write('<div id="slide1"><img src="http://www.hrhsfalcons.com/assets/img/aca_' +aca+ '.jpg" /></div>');
      document.write('<div id="slide2"><img src="http://www.hrhsfalcons.com/assets/img/ath_' +ath+ '.jpg" /></div>');
      document.write('<div id="slide3"><img src="http://www.hrhsfalcons.com/assets/img/act_' +act+ '.jpg" /></div>');
      document.write('</div></div>');
      </script>
</div>
```

Comment: if its a page reload then you could simply use php or any other server  side languages along with sql query to randomly select the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this its working http://jsfiddle.net/qk3ES/

```
  <body onload="loadRandomImages()">


<div id="main_slide">
    <div id="slide-buttons">
      <button class='prev' onclick='mySwipe.prev()'>&lt;</button>
      <a class='links' href="http://www.hrhsfalcons.com/academics">Academics</a>
      <a class='links' href="http://www.hrhsfalcons.com/athletics">Athletics</a>
      <a class='links' href="http://www.hrhsfalcons.com/clubs">Activities</a>
      <button class='next' onclick='mySwipe.next()'>&gt;</button>
      <div id='mySwipe' class='swipe'>
        <div class='swipe-wrap'>
          <div id="slide1"><img id="slide1Img" /></div>
          <div id="slide2"><img id="slide2Img" /></div>
          <div id="slide3"><img id="slide3Img" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

      <script>
          function loadRandomImages() {
              var aca = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
              var ath = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
              var act = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

              var slide1Src = 'http://www.hrhsfalcons.com/assets/img/aca_'+ aca +'.jpg';
              var slide2Src = 'http://www.hrhsfalcons.com/assets/img/ath_' +ath+ '.jpg';
              var slide3Src = 'http://www.hrhsfalcons.com/assets/img/act_' +act+ '.jpg';

              document.getElementById('slide1Img').src = slide1Src;
              document.getElementById('slide2Img').src = slide2Src;
              document.getElementById('slide3Img').src = slide3Src;
          }
      </script>
</div>



    </body>
```

You can add 1 button to refresh the images and in button click just call loadRandomImages() function.
So that only three images will be refreshed not the whole document.